# Auto login after register in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I want when I finished register it redirects me to the dashboard page (Auto login after the register).

this is the user register code :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();


        $apprenant = Apprenant::create([
            'nom' => $request['nom'],
            'prenom' => $request['prenom'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'niveau' => $request['niveau'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),

        ]);


            return redirect('/apprenant/dashboard');
    }
```

But when I finished registring it redirects me to the login page

Comment: Use `auth()->login($apparenant)` before the redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if you are create a guard then run this code for after register login
`Auth::guard(guard_name)->loginUsingId($id);`

// example

```
    public function register(Request $req)
{
    $user = new User; // define here your model
    $user->name = $req->name;
    $user->email = $req->email;
    $user->password = Hash::make($req->password);

    if($user->save()){
        Auth::guard(guard_name)->loginUsingId($user->id);
    }

}
```

// logout overite

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::guard('guard_name')->logout();
    return redirect("login_path");
}
```

Comment: undefined variable $id ??

Comment: hi here pass your user id

Comment: first step save data in your database then pass id here

Comment: wait i give you a best example

Comment: i passed $apprenant->id and it worked but when i logout it show me that the App\User class don't found

Comment: can you shere your logout method.

Comment: create one method 
then run this code 
`Auth::guard('guard_name')->logout()`;

Comment: in my controllers there's not a logout method ! I guess I'm using the default laravel logout method

Comment: bro run `php artisan route:list` command for see your route then go to controller create one more method and overrite this code.

Comment: changed in my answer try follow step

Comment: but in the view i called {{ route('logout') }}

Comment: this action go to your login controller go to login controller and create method logout look like as my ans same then run this code

Comment: and import user model in controller 

`use App\User` in top of controller down of namspace

Comment: are you tryied overrite logout function in logicontroller overite this its working fine.

Comment: just a second friend

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new user, create() method, should return a new model object. 
 Use `Auth::loginUsingId($apprenant->id);` before redirecting to dashboard:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();


        $apprenant = Apprenant::create([
            'nom' => $request['nom'],
            'prenom' => $request['prenom'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'niveau' => $request['niveau'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),

        ]);

            Auth::loginUsingId($apprenant->id);
            return redirect('/apprenant/dashboard');
    }
```

source
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Comment: It worked dude but when I logout it shows me that the class App\user don't found !

Answer (score 0):

Write this line before redirecting to the dashboard:

```
\Auth::login($apprenant);
```

or just,

```
auth()->login($apprenant);
```

That means, you code will look like:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();


        $apprenant = Apprenant::create([
            'nom' => $request['nom'],
            'prenom' => $request['prenom'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'niveau' => $request['niveau'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),

        ]);

        //login the user
        \Auth::login($apprenant);

        return redirect('/apprenant/dashboard');
    }
```

Comment: It worked dude but I'm using guards when I logout it shows me that the class App\user don't found !

Comment: @Belhedi where does it go after you logout?

Comment: @Belhedi please post your full controller code. The error you mentioned: 'App\User not found' is because you are using it somewhere in your code but not importing the class 'User'. try ' use App\User; ' in whatever controller is throwing that error. It should solve the problem

Comment: I don't think so friend because when I added the line that you gave me that error shows when I logout cause I'm using the default laravel logout besides I'm using guards...